# IPhone Storyboard - Assigning class to view controller in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have created a simple app using storyboard. In storyboard file, i have dragged one view controller. I want to assign a class to the newly added view controller. To do this, I clicked on new file in Xcode, clicked on `Objective c class`, entered class name `MyViewController` and subclass is of UIViewController. I went back to storyboard and clicked on `Custom class` type and given MyViewController in class tab. But it is not taking this. If i unselect the viewcontroller and select, custom class shows "UIView" again.

I am using Xcode version 4.3.3 (4E3002).

Comment: Also, after dragging view controller to storyboard, custom class type shows "UIView" instead of "UIViewController". I doubt this is the issue. Please help why i am getting UIView instead of UIViewController.

Comment: Problem is resolved. I was clicking inside view controller, so it was showing "UIView".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

xcode does this problem even if everything is fine. Close your xcode project and then quit xcode. Start again and you will be able to find the class in the dropdown menu.